# Data Integration Approach

Tags: xml, xsd

Im trying push some data into a CRM system via an XML import.

I have XML Schemas for the CRM system (XSD's) which are pretty complex (big files with lots of namesapces), I'm struggling to figure out what the XML should look like and the namesapces are not helping at all.

I need an easy way to prototype the XML documents, once I have a set of working XML templates I can code up the data feed properly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've been using Liquid XML Studio for ages, the XSD Diagrams make it easy to understand the XSD's. There is also a feature where you can create a sample XML document, this can sometimes be a good start. Finally the intellisense in the XML Editor gives you all the options and ensures you have the correct namespaces.

Comment: Thanks - Liquid XML seems to be doing what I want, I tried to get Visual studio up and running, but it seems a bit hit and miss with the auto complete options.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the connection works both ways.  Can you tell the CRM to output some XML so that you can have a look at it?

Comment: You would have thought, but it only seems to return a very basic response, and the interface only seems to be for importing data. I gave up on the C++ API interface as it was way to buggy. The thing was written by a small software house and they have little intrest in improving it or supporting it. If it were up to me I'd scrap it, then again if it was up to me we'd be doing a lot of things differntly...

Answer (score 0):

I sounds like you just need a good [XML Editor](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/XmlStudio/Free-Xml-Editor.aspx).

I would go with Liquid XML Studio (the free version would do everything you need by the sound of it).

Or Visual Studio 2003 or above. The intellisense is OK but can be a pain to setup - have a look at "[How to configure the Visual Studio 2005 IDE to use custom XSD files for IntelliSense](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2005/12/07/501466.aspx)"

If you want schema visualisation though [Liquid XML](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/XmlStudio/Free-Xsd-Editor.aspx) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Brian,

If you are working in Microsoft .NET, you can generate C# or VB classes from your XML schemas with [XSD.EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.71).aspx).